# Derivative of piecewise function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, piecewise

I tried to find $f'(0)$ of this function:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x\cdot\sin(\frac{1}{x}) & \text{if $x\ne0$} \\ 0 & \text{if $x=0$} \end{cases}$$

This is what I tried in Mathematica:

```
f[x_] = Piecewise[{{x*Sin[1/x], x != 0}, {0, x == 0}}]
f'[0]
```

Mathematica gives the answer $0$, while the answer should be $undefined$, also see this discussion: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1551257/derivative-of-piece-wise-function-at-x-0

Any idea why Mathematica doesn't give the correct anwer?

Comment: *Mathematica* takes symbolic derivatives and intergrals of `Piecewise` functions in a piecewise fashion, i.e. `D` gets applied to each part of `Piecewise` and then kicks back the derivatives of each condition. Examine the output of `D[f[x],x]`.

Comment: If Mathematica must work piece by piece on the derivative of a Piecewise function, it seems that a better choice for intervals of width 0, would be undefined, since the derivative is undefined for a function that exists only at a single point.

Comment: @JohnMcGee In some cases the derivative still exists, if the interval of width 0 makes the function continuous.

Comment: To get the correct answer, evaluate `(f[h] - f[0])/h // Simplify[#, h != 0] &` so as to obtain `Sin[1/h]`. Then either look at a plot of that output function of `h` or else evaluate `Limit[Sin[1/h], h -> 0]` to obtain `Interval[{-1,1}]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mathematica is being inconsistent in how it is treating the derivative for a piecewise function (this seems like a bug to me).  We can look at a simpler example to see this, which will point towards a workaround,

```
pwf1[x_] := Piecewise[{
    {3 x, x != 0},
    {5 x, x == 0}}];
pwf2[x_] := Piecewise[{
    {3 x, x < 0},
    {5 x, x == 0},
    {3 x, x > 0}}];
pwf1'[0]
pwf2'[0]
(* 5 *)
(* 3 *)
```

These are both the same function, and if we take the derivative manually, then we get the same answer:

```
Limit[(pwf1[0 + h] - pwf1[0])/h, h -> 0]
Limit[(pwf2[0 + h] - pwf2[0])/h, h -> 0]
(* 3 *)
(* 3 *)
```

So apparently it is better to define the piecewise regions more explicitly,

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{
   {x*Sin[1/x], x > 0},
   {0, x == 0},
   {x*Sin[1/x], x < 0}
   }]
f'[0]
(* Indeterminate *)
```

This is the same answer you get when you take the analytic derivative and substitute `x=0`,

```
func[x_] := x Sin[1/x];
func'[0]
```

> During evaluation of In[149]:= Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0
>   encountered. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[149]:= Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0
>   encountered. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[149]:= Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0
>   encountered. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[149]:= General::stop: Further output of
>   Power::infy will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

```
(* Indeterminate *)
```

Comment: Indeed, I found the same. Strange that defining the regions more explicit will generate different results.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is perhaps clearer without the `Piecewise`. Let

```
g[x_] = x*Sin[1/x]
```

Then 
    D[g[x], x]

```
-(Cos[1/x]/x) + Sin[1/x]
```

To find what is happening as x approaches the discontinuity:

```
Limit[D[g[x], x], x -> 0]

Interval[{-∞, ∞}]
```

which is pretty much saying that the derivative doesn't exist at this point.

Comment: I am specifically interested in what happens with the derivative if we make the original function continuous. By saying f(x)=0 the original function becomes continuous, but still the derivative cannot be defined at f'(0).

Comment: Well... the g[x] suggested above is continuous, as you can see by taking `Limit[g[x], x -> 0]`, which of course gives 0.

Comment: For it to be continuous, both the limit and the value of f at x should be equal. In your function f(0) is not defined.