# Derivatives of piecewise functions of functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, piecewise

#### Background

Derivatives of piecewise functions in *Mathematica* are computed according to special rules. According the [`Piecewise` documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) (see *Possible Issues*),

> Derivatives are computed piece-by-piece, unless the function is univariate in a real variable.

This distinction is important for piecewise functions that have a pointwise definition (such as a discontinuity). In this case, if *Mathematica* can determine that the variable is real, it finds the derivative at the discontinuity by looking at the derivatives on each side, rather that at the function definition at the discontinuity. This is somewhat discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100852/derivative-of-piecewise-function).

In general, this behavior is intelligent and useful. Consider the function

$$
f(b, p) = \sqrt{\frac{b - 1}{e^{(b - 1)p} - 1}}
$$

which is, in fact, continuous, but evaluates to `Indeterminate` at $b = 1$. Its derivatives with respect to the first argument will have the same problem. Now, If we define $f$ via `Piecewise`, we can put the appropriate limit in by hand.

```
f[b_, p_] := Piecewise[
  {{Sqrt[(b - 1)/(Exp[(b - 1) p] - 1)], b < 1 || b > 1},
   {Sqrt[1/p], b == 1}}
 ]
```

To get derivatives, we can differentiate as normal:

```
D[f[b, p], b] // Simplify
```

> $$
>   \begin{cases}
> -\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{\frac{1}{p}}} & b = 1 \\[6pt]
> \frac{e^{(b-1) p} (1 + p - b p) - 1}{2 \sqrt{\frac{b-1}{e^{(b-1) p} - 1}} \left(e^{(b-1) p}- 1 \right)^2} & \text{True}
>   \end{cases}
>   $$

Even though the function value at $b = 1$ does not depend on $b$, the derivative is correctly found because *Mathematica* looks at the surrounding region. Multiple derivatives are fine, too.

---

#### The Problem

***However, if the variable defining the piecewise regions is a function of the variable of differentiation, the differentiation always proceeds piece-by-piece.***

```
D[f[g[b], p], b] // Simplify
```

> $$
>   \begin{cases}
> 0 & g(b) = 1 \\[6pt]
> \frac{e^{(g(b)-1) p} (1 + p - g(b) p) - 1}{2 \sqrt{\frac{g(b)-1}{e^{(g(b)-1) p} - 1}} \left(e^{(g(b)-1) p}- 1 \right)^2} g^\prime (b) & \text{True}
>   \end{cases}
>   $$

*The derivative at the discontinuity vanishes.* Note that `D[f[g, p], b, NonConstants -> {g}]` and `Dt[f[g, p], b, Constants -> {b}]` also exhibit this behavior. Neither does it matter that `g` is unspecified (`g = Sin` will do the same thing).

It appears that this occurs because with a compound variable `Piecewise` no longer knows that the variable is real (I'm not sure why), so the derivative is computed piece-by-piece, and the derivative of the constant (in $b$) piece at $b = 1$ goes to zero. One can check this by adding some $b$-dependence and verifying that it behaves as expected for piece-by-piece differentiation:

```
h[b_, p_] := Piecewise[
  {{Sqrt[(b - 1)/(Exp[(b - 1) p] - 1)], b < 1 || b > 1},
   {b Sqrt[1/p], b == 1}}
 ]

D[h[g[b], p], b] // Simplify
```

> $$
>   \begin{cases}
> \sqrt{\frac{1}{p}} \, g^\prime (b) & g(b) = 1 \\[6pt]
> \frac{e^{(g(b)-1) p} (1 + p - g(b) p) - 1}{2 \sqrt{\frac{g(b)-1}{e^{(g(b)-1) p} - 1}} \left(e^{(g(b)-1) p}- 1 \right)^2} g^\prime (b) & \text{True}
>   \end{cases}
>   $$

Of course, this is only an issue for piecewise functions that have a pointwise definition that doesn't carry the full variable dependence necessary to compute derivatives.

***Is this behavior intended? How do I work around it?***

Ideally, one should be able to take as many derivatives of $f(g(b), p)$ with respect to $b$ (providing $g$ is well-behaved) as are possible of $f(b, p)$. For the purposes of this question, treat $g$ as an unspecified, but well-behaved function -- our lack of knowledge about its behavior should be parametrized by the appearance of $g^\prime(b)$ and higher derivatives in the output. **Essentially, *Mathematica* is unable to work out the chain rule for piecewise functions with a pointwise definition, since it differentiates them piece-by-piece, and I want to know the best way to deal with this.**

I ran into this problem because I need to be able to take derivatives of a piecewise function of a dependent variable with respect to an independent variable so that I can use equations containing that function in `NDSolve`. Practically, it is easy enough to get one or two correct derivatives by defining the function value at the tricky point as some number of terms in its series expansion to give it explicit variable-dependence, but I am interested in a more general solution.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: How do you know if a general function of g[b] is differentiable at all? I mean, when we do not know the definition we can't guarantee the derivative exists at that point for the point-wise function. If it exists, and is equal from left and right, i guess we can define a function to use the definition of a derivative using limits, or, do a numerical differentiation?

Comment: @MathX While you wrote this, I answered with essentially the same general thought...

Comment: @Jens yeah I was editing when I saw an answer was posted haha you beat  me to it. This question actually made me curious to see if Mathematica has a built-in Frechet derivative function which apparently it doesn't.

Comment: @MathX In this case, I know that the function `g[b]` is differentiable.

Comment: @MathX also, take a look at [`DifferenceQuotient`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DifferenceQuotient.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously you can get derivatives only if the function actually has a derivative, and this is true for the example in the question. Your function is even continuous at the point in question. This means singularity is removable, and therefore we should *not* have to use `Piecewise` for that single point at all. Here is how you can avoid its use when you suspect that the derivative exists everywhere:

```
f[x_, p_] := 
 Module[{b}, Limit[Sqrt[(b - 1)/(Exp[(b - 1) p] - 1)], b -> x]]

D[f[b, p], b] // Simplify

(*
==> (-1 + 
 E^((-1 + b) p) (1 + p - b p))/(2 Sqrt[(-1 + b)/(-1 + 
  E^((-1 + b) p))] (-1 + E^((-1 + b) p))^2)
*)

D[f[g[b], p], b] // Simplify

(*
==> -(((1 - E^(p (-1 + g[b])) (1 + p) + 
    E^(p (-1 + g[b])) p g[b]) Derivative[1][g][b])/(
 2 (-1 + E^(p (-1 + g[b])))^2 Sqrt[(-1 + g[b])/(-1 + E^(
   p (-1 + g[b])))]))
*)
```

The trick is simply to evaluate the function as a `Limit`. With that, the result contains no case distinctions.

**Edit**

Having the derivatives as above, you may then of course encounter the same  removable singularity and therefore would need to evaluate these results using `Limit` as well. I.e., to do the substitution mentioned in the comment, you would have to do

```
Limit[D[f[g[b], p], b], g[b] -> 1]

(* ==> -(Derivative[1][g][b]/(4 Sqrt[1/p])) *)
```

**Edit 2**

The comments made it clear that the a formulation in terms of `Piecewise` is indeed preferred. So here is an alternative approach that relies on the idea (mentioned in the comment) that `f` itself may only be needed for numerical arguments:

```
ClearAll[f];
fOrig[x_, p_] := 
 D[Piecewise[{{Sqrt[(x - 1)/(Exp[(x - 1) p] - 1)], 
     x < 1 || x > 1}, {Sqrt[1/p], x == 1}}], x]

Derivative[1, 0][f][b_, p_] := 
 Module[{x}, Simplify[fOrig[x, p]] /. x -> b]

f[b_?NumericQ, p_] := fOrig[b, p]

D[f[b, p], b]
```

> $$\begin{cases}
>  -\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{\frac{1}{p}}} & b=1 \\
>  \frac{e^{(b-1) p} (-b p+p+1)-1}{2
>    \sqrt{\frac{b-1}{e^{(b-1) p}-1}} \left(e^{(b-1)
>    p}-1\right)^2} & \text{True}
> \end{cases}$$

```
D[f[g[b], p], b]
```

> $$g'(b)
> \begin{cases}
>  -\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{\frac{1}{p}}} & g(b)=1 \\
>  \frac{e^{p (g(b)-1)} (-g(b) p+p+1)-1}{2 \left(-1+e^{p
>    (g(b)-1)}\right)^2 \sqrt{\frac{g(b)-1}{-1+e^{p
>    (g(b)-1)}}}} & \text{True} \\
> \end{cases}
> $$

This gives the correct results because I defined the derivative directly to use the first differentiation that worked properly (without inner function), and then manually added the chain rule.

Comment: The difficulty is that I want the derivatives, which are also continuous, to give the appropriate limit at the point in question. However with this `Limit`-based definition, `(D[f[g[b], p], b]) /. g[b] -> 1` returns `Indeterminate`.

Comment: @Virgil The substitution `g[b] -> 1` isn't going to work anyway because it leaves `g'` untouched. But I think I understand what you mean. You want to keep `g` unspecified until the end, not give it a definition at the beginning, right? Then I guess the limit approach wouldn't help. I think it only works if the inner function is already defined so that the singular point in the outer function can actually be identified.

Comment: @Virgil I added the "workaround" for the case you mentioned, showing the extent to which `Limit` can do what you ask. However, it's probably not as "automated" as you want. However, not knowing anything about `g`, I don't see a better alternative right now.

Comment: Correct. In the end, `g` is going to be a dependent variable in `NDSolve`, so it needs to be unspecified. I also need the equations it occurs in (which include the piecewise function and derivatives thereof) to be well-defined (as in not `Indeterminate`) everywhere. I played around with `Limit` myself for a while, but abandoned it for `Piecewise`, since it cannot pass along the limit to derivatives.

Comment: I would like to automate it. Perhaps a new `myLimit`-type function that has `HoldFirst`, passes `D` inside, and evaluates only for numerical arguments would work

Comment: Very nice! With the above, higher-order derivatives in `b` won't work, but that should be easy enough to add. This is probably the best option, but I want to leave the question open for a little longer.

Answer (score 2):

I have accepted [Jens](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/245/jens)' method, since it works and with a minimum of inconvenience. However, it is more useful when generalized to multiple derivatives, so I will show what I did to accomplish that below. I also want to present two other work-arounds that I came up with. I do not like either as well as Jens', but they may be useful in cases where one does not want to use a numeric function.

### Jens' method for general derivatives

To correctly obtain more complicated derivatives, we simply need to make a general `Derivative` definition for $f$ that is numeric in the appropriate argument:

```
fOrig[b_, p_] := Piecewise[
  {{Sqrt[(b - 1)/(Exp[(b - 1) p] - 1)], b < 1 || b > 1},
   {Sqrt[1/p], b == 1}}
 ]

f[b_?NumericQ, p_] := fOrig[b, p]

Derivative[n__][f][b_?NumericQ, p_] := Derivative[n][fOrig][b, p]
```

This is the approach I have decided to take in my own work.

### A special derivative

It one want's to avoid numeric definitions as in the above, one option is to define a special derivative that uses `Inactivate` and `Activate` to hold particular functions inactive during the course of derivation, restoring them after any chain and/or product rules have been worked out. The effect is the same as that achieved by making the argument numeric.

```
SetAttributes[myD, HoldFirst];
Options@myD = Options@D;
myD[expr_, patt_, x__, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Activate[
  D[Inactivate[expr, patt], x, opts], 
  patt]
```

Here, the argument *`patt`* takes a pattern, and any parts of *`expr`* matching that pattern are inactivated before `D` is applied and reactivated after. It can be applied as so:

```
myD[fOrig[g[b], p], fOrig, b]
```

> $$
>   g^\prime (b) \,
>   \begin{cases}
> - \frac{1}{4\sqrt{\frac{1}{p}}} & g(b) = 1 \\[6pt]
> \frac{e^{(g(b)-1) p} (1 + p - g(b) p) - 1}{2 \sqrt{\frac{g(b)-1}{e^{(g(b)-1) p} - 1}} \left(e^{(g(b)-1) p}- 1 \right)^2} & \text{True}
>   \end{cases}
>   $$

Higher-order derivatives work as well.

I am not as fond of this method as it requires the use of a special new derivative, which I find cumbersome.

### A special limit

One other thing one can do is to work with the piece-by-piece differentiation of `Piecewise` and modify the limiting value itself, so that when differentiated it gives the proper result. I came up with this:

```
SeriesLimit[f_, {x_, x0_?NumericQ}] := SeriesCoefficient[f, {x, x0, 0}]
Derivative[0, {0, n_}][seriesLimit][f_, {x_, x0_}] := seriesLimit[D[f, {x, n}], {x, x0}]
Derivative[n_, {0, 0}][seriesLimit][f_, {x_, x0_}] := seriesLimit[1, {x, x0}]
Times[a___, seriesLimit[f_, {x_, x0_}], b___] ^:= seriesLimit[a f b, {x_, x0_}]
```

`seriesLimit` is a wrapper that holds its arguments until the argument *`x0`* is numeric, at which point it takes the first term in the series expansion of $f$ around $x_0$, that is, $f(x_0)$. Under differentiation, it passes derivatives with respect to *`x0`* inside to *`f`* as derivatives with respect to *`x`*, and collects terms generated by derivatives with respect to other arguments back inside. This behavior is probably not robust, but it is sufficient here.

```
D[seriesLimit[g[x, p], {x, b}], b]
```

> ```
> seriesLimit[Derivative[1, 0][g][x, p], {x, y}]
> ```

```
D[seriesLimit[g[x, p], {x, h[b]}], b, b]
```

> ```
> seriesLimit[h''[b] Derivative[1, 0][g][x, p], {x, h[b]}] + seriesLimit[h'[b]^2 Derivative[2, 0][g][x, p], {x, h[b]}]
> ```

```
seriesLimit[Sqrt[(x - 1)/(Exp[(x - 1) p] - 1)], {x, 1}]
```

> ```
> Sqrt[1/p]
> ```

It can be used in `Piecewise` to alleviate the difficulty at hand:

```
fNew[b_, p_] := Piecewise[
  {{Sqrt[(b - 1)/(Exp[(b - 1) p] - 1)], b < 1 || b > 1},
   {seriesLimit[Sqrt[(x - 1)/(Exp[(x - 1) p] - 1)], {x, b}], b == 1}}
 ]

D[fNew[g[b], p], b]
```

> $$
>   \begin{cases}
> g^\prime (b) \, 
> \frac{e^{(g(b)-1) p} (1 + p - g(b) p) - 1}{2 \sqrt{\frac{g(b)-1}{e^{(g(b)-1) p} - 1}} \left(e^{(g(b)-1) p}- 1 \right)^2} & g(b) > 1 \| \, g(b) < 1 \\[6pt]
> \text{seriesLimit} \Big[ g^\prime (b)  \, \frac{e^{(x-1) p} (1 + p - x p) - 1}{2 \sqrt{\frac{x-1}{e^{(x-1) p} - 1}} \left(e^{(x-1) p}- 1 \right)^2}, \{x, g(b)\} \Big] & \text{True} 
>   \end{cases}
>   $$

In the case that the piecewise variable is not a function (i.e. $g(b) \rightarrow b$), under differentiation the derivative at the discontinuity is calculated by the limiting procedure outlined in the question, and the `seriesLimit` drops out.