# Direct and easy calculation of the N-th derivative of a function at 0?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Does Mathematica have an easy way to calculate the n-th derivative of a function at zero?

I was looking for something along the way `D[e^x,{x,n,0}]`.

How do I do that?

Mathematica doesn't know that it needs to remove the singularity.

Here's the code (notice the pole is removed with the multiplication):

```
f[x_] := 2 Pi x Csc[2 Pi x];
Derivative[3][f][0]    
D[2 Pi x Csc[2 Pi x], {x, 1}] /. x -> 0
```

Comment: @Brad Thanks, I will use coefficient then.

Comment: Ok, I'm really frustrated that Mathematica has these glitches

Comment: You haven't specified how `f[0]` is to be defined -- well, the expression you gave is undefined.  How is *Mathematica* to know whether you want the hole in the domain to be removed or not and how you want the function to extended? Even in mathematical papers, authors will indicate what's intended.  That said, there are known problems with differentiation of piecewise function: [(100852)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100852), [(111698)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/111698)

Comment: @MichaelE2 If one uses the coefficient formula, SeriesCoefficient[Exp[x], {x, 0, n}], it gives the correct answer. I disagree with your argument, the coefficients of the power expansion of 2 Pi x Csc[2 Pi x] about 0 all exist, therefore the n-th derivatives at 0 should be those coefficients.

Comment: I disagree with your lax treatment of expressions: The first term in the series expansion of `f[x]` is `f[0]`, which is undefined by your definition. So are all the other terms since the definition of $f^{(n)}(0)$ ultimately depends on $f(0}$. I think I know what you would do: replace them by their limits at $0$. Is there a CAS that does this automatically? In any case *M* does not. I guess we'll just disagree.

Comment: Why do you need the nth derivative? Wouldn't getting the series be more useful?

Comment: Updated my answer to return the $n^{th}$ derivative at zero for a function with a removable singularity (such as the example given $\frac{1}{\textrm{sinc} \, 2\pi x}$) without needing to resort to series.  I do agree, using series is also a nice solution!

Comment: @Michael, do you remember [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128439)?

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive I remember the approach, but I forgot I'd posted something here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
D[Exp[x], {x, n}] /. x->0
```

> 1

Also possible is:

```
n! SeriesCoefficient[Exp[x], {x, 0, n}, Assumptions->n>0]
```

> 1

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

If you want to *define* the function at zero, to be its limit there ...

```
g[x_,0]  := 1/Sinc[2 \[Pi] x];
g[x_,k_] := D[g[x,k-1],x] // FullSimplify;
f[x_,k_] := If[x == 0, Limit[g[a,k], a -> 0], g[x,k]];
```

The first few derivatives of $f(x)$ at $x=0$ are tabulated:

```
Table[f[0,k],{k,6}]
```

and are:

$\{0, \frac{4 \pi^2}{3}, 0, \frac{112 \pi^4}{15}, 0, \frac{1984 \pi^6}{21}\}.$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91197/discussion-on-answer-by-mjw-direct-and-easy-calculation-of-the-n-th-derivative-o).